# AutoPlay Unable to Work on Mobile Browsers

Tags: android, iframe, html5-video, autoplay

I have been trying to get this piece of code to autoplay on mobile devices.  It currently works fine and autoplays on the desktop with multiple browsers.

Please let me know what I need to do in order to get this code to work on mobile devices.

```
 <iframe src="careerVid.mp4?    
autoplay=1&loop=1&title=0&byline=0&portrait=0" style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%;"     frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Update to this question:

I have used the following code structure to try and add this video which is in an mp4 format to have it work.  It currently does not "autoplay" when loading in chrome on an android or iphone.  Please let me know if there are any errors present or how to go about updating the code snippet properly.

This is the code that I added the controls muted, but this doesn't work.

Thank you

```
 <iframe controls muted src="player.vimeo.com/video/…; style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%;" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least on Chrome on Android autoplay is disabled and a user gesture is required to start playing (Not sure about Firefox, but could be the same).

Chrom on Android has now allowed  to autoplay muted videos (see this [bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=617595)), maybe this feature helps you if audio is irrelevant.

Comment: Audio IS irrelevant.  Thank you, I should have stated that in the question.  What about for chrome or safari on iphones?

Comment: I think that this goes for Chrome on all mobile platforms, as for Safari, no clue, just test it.

Comment: I tried adding the muted attribute to the code, but it still doesn't work in Chrome.  Let me know if it looks like there is an error with the code.  Thank You.           <video controls muted style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%;" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscree> 
<source src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/156889858?autoplay=1&loop=1&title=0&byline=0&portrait=0" type="video/mp4"></video>

Comment: SKIP THE LAST COMMENT -----SORRY----- This is the code that I added the controls muted, but this doesn't work. Thanks  <iframe controls muted src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/156889858?autoplay=1&loop=1&title=0&byline=0&portrait=0" style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%;" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>

Comment: First of all, dont put the code in comments, edit/update the question instead. Ill check on an actual android phone tomorrow.

Comment: @TryingtoLearnJavascript I looked at the code and well the attributes from the `iframe` you have are not applied to the actual `video` element generated. So I assume it's up to you to learn how the vimeo player works to actually tell it to be muted (so that the generated `video` element has the `muted` attribute) or just fall back to using plain `video` tag.